# How to fix Nextcloud's cron job seems not to be working?

Tags: docker, cron, nextcloud

How to trigger *www-data* php script from **cron** of *root* user ?

After running **Nextcloud** from docker image cron job is not working: *`cron job seems not to be working`*

*www-data* user not able to start the cron job, and root user not have access to run *www-data*'s php

```
Console has to be executed with the user that owns the file
config/config.php Current user id: 0
```

Comment: There is a section in the documentation about your options: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/background_jobs_configuration.html

Comment: in my example the cron is installed for root user and not recommended for www-data user, so the below solution is running the cron from root user and executing the script as www-data user who is the owner of the nextcloud process

Comment: Hm ... well ... `cron` is installed on the system, every user can use it. And as typical for unixoid systems those usages have nothing to do with each other. So yes, `root` can setup cron jobs, but any other user can do that too. `cron` is a system service, not something installed for a specific user. Also there is no such thing as a "nextcloud process". Nextcloud is a php based solution, there are many processes involed that belong to other services, typically the http server or the fpm server, depending on your setup. But there is not process for nextcloud as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is a working solution assuming you've installed cron `apt-get install cron`

1. As root user run

```
crontab -e
```

2. Append this line which will run php script as `www-data` user

```
* * * * * su www-data -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/cron.php"
```

2. Restart cron service

```
 /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the path to the php interpreter

```
which php
```

Locate the cron.php file

```
locate cron.php
```

As root run crontab with the -u flag to specify the user and -e to edit the cron file. In this case the user is www-data and the cron job will run as that user.

```
crontab -u www-data -e
```

Append this line to run cron.php every 5 minutes. Modify the locations of php and cron.php according to your system

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/cron.php
```

Save the file, wait ten minutes, then check your log files to ensure it is working.

```
journalctl -u cron --since '20 minutes ago'
```